# Enable the cluster autoscaler on existing Azure AKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to enable cluster Autoscaling on existing AKS Cluster using Azure CLI. Please find the below command which I have used.

```
az aks update --resource-group prod-rg --name prod-aks-cluster  --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 3 --max-count 4
```

I am getting the following exception while executing the above command.

Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: AgentPool 'agentpool' has set auto scaling as enabled but is not on Virtual Machine Scale Sets, this is not allowed. Please see https://aka.ms/aks-vmss-enablement for more details.

From the above exception, I have understood that the Virtual Machine Scale Sets is not enabled in my Cluster. Is there any way I can enable the Virtual Machine Scale Sets in existing Cluster or Enable Cluster Autoscalar in existing Cluster without Virtual Machine Scale Sets. Any help will be appreciated.

AKS Cluster version : 1.13.12
Azure CLI Version : 2.0.77

I have referred to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler

Comment: I have the same questions and problems. This GitHub issue is relevant. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24942 Unfortunately, we cant enable vmss after the cluster is created.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible but just not the recommended way to do it anymore. The  [method](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/cluster-autoscaler-1.19.0/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/README.md#aks--availability-set) uses a k8s feature/resource instead of support from AKS.

Fill the placeholders in https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/cluster-autoscaler-1.19.0/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/examples/cluster-autoscaler-aks.yaml and create the set of resources with `kubectl create -f cluster-autoscaler-aks.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the

```
--vm-set-type VirtualMachineScaleSets
```

parameter.